# Jenkins Multibranch project trowes fatal: ambiguous argument 'upstream/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree. for the PR build

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, multibranch-pipeline

I am working on a project same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58252024/jenkins-git-only-build-if-pr-introduced-changes-in-subdirectory/63248679#63248679). Even though I used the same solution still i'am getting below error. Is anything updated in git recently? or anyone have solution to fix it?

```
16:48:06  + git rev-parse upstream/master
16:48:06  fatal: ambiguous argument 'upstream/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
16:48:06  Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
16:48:06  'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
16:48:06  upstream/master
```

Comment: It is telling you that the branch `upstream/master` does not exist on the server.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution finally. adding ref specs to project fixed the issue.[image]

Comment: This helped me greatly.